# Displaying multivalued attributes from model in columns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am just kicking things off with Kendo UI, I could not find a way to display multivalued attributes in a column, with respect to a value in the preceeding column. Here is the representational mockup of the view that I want:

[image: Grid view with 3 columns]

The values in column 2 and 3 belong to the Value 1, 2 and 3 respectively. I have the model, which is a `list` containing another list for columns 2 and 3. Here is what I have so far:

```
@model List<Customer>
<div class="left" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Customer Data</span></div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Customer>()
   .Name("gvCustomerData")
   .Columns(columns =>
       {
           columns.Bound(Model => Model.CustomerName);
       })
       .Pageable()
       .Sortable()
       .Scrollable()
       .Filterable()
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax().Model(model => model.Id(Model => Model.CustomerId))
                           .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomerData", "Customer", new { DeptId= @ViewBag.DeptId})))
    )
</div>
```

In this case, the values could be the customers phone numbers or projects that he is working on. I do not want to manually iterate over the Model List and construct the raw HTML against that. Can `Kendo` help to simplify the process?

Comment: You will have to rely on templates to make that happen, possibly group column 1 as well, depending on how you want the grid to display and function

Comment: Templates render data in the single row, I need it in different rows.. Would defining Schema/Model help in this case?

Comment: Well you can use nested grids with detail templates if that is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863581/how-to-achieve-n-level-nested-hierarchy-in-kendo-ui-grid-using-asp-net-mvc. Or use tables as templates and if you require inline editing you can hook up the template to an obserable with kendo.bind() and data-bind attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Kendo UI does support merged column headers, it doesn't seem to support your requirement.

However, I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708865/How-to-merge-cells-in-Kendo-ui-Grid) piece of code, perhaps it helps you:

```
function mergeGridRows(gridId, colTitle) {
    $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-content>table').each(function (index, item) { 
        var dimension_col = 1;
        // First, scan first row of headers for the "Dimensions" column.
        $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-header>.k-grid-header-wrap>table').find('th').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == colTitle) { 
                // first_instance holds the first instance of identical td
                var first_instance = null;     
                $(item).find('tr').each(function () {     
                    // find the td of the correct column (determined by the colTitle)
                    var dimension_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + dimension_col + ')');

                    if (first_instance == null) {
                        first_instance = dimension_td;
                    } else if (dimension_td.text() == first_instance.text()) {
                        // if current td is identical to the previous
                        // then remove the current td
                        dimension_td.remove();
                        // increment the rowspan attribute of the first instance
                        first_instance.attr('rowspan', typeof first_instance.attr('rowspan') == "undefined" ? 2 : first_instance.attr('rowspan') + 1);
                    } else {
                        // this cell is different from the last
                        first_instance = dimension_td;
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            dimension_col++;
        }); 
    });
}
```